# How to make a grid of scaled images match the height of its div sibling?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a grid composed of a variable number of images, and I want that grid be the same height as its sibling. But it seems like, from all the examples I've seen online, you have to hardcode pixel values for the images. I don't want to do that. In the following example, I just want the images to be arranged in a 3x3 grid that is the exact same height as the div next to it. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.data table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.data table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="data">
      <p>information</p>
      <p>more information</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Field1</td>
            <td>banana</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Field2</td>
            <td>apple</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Field3</td>
            <td>pear</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Field4</td>
            <td>mango</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="img-grid">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg" class="">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg">
      <img src="https://cdn.travelpulse.com/images/d3a9edf4-a957-df11-b491-006073e71405/e864929d-127a-4caf-9a15-7f9cd45160f0/630x355.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: original example code wasn't a good representation of the issue, so I updated it.

Also, I should point out, that if you run the code snippet in a small enough window, it may look like it's working, but if you open it in fullscreen, it will be clear that it does not work.

Comment: if you fix the typo (the `;` after display: grid) your code seems to work fine

Comment: you're right. I updated the example, as I had oversimplified the original.